# How to get the actual learning rate in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, learning-rate

I'm trying to find the appropriate learning rate for my Neural Network using PyTorch. I've implemented the `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR` to get the learning rate. But I'm unable to figure out what is the actual learning rate that should be selected. The dataset is MNIST_TINY.

**Code:**

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR(optimizer, base_lr=1e-7, max_lr=0.1, step_size_up=5., mode='triangular')

lrs= []
for epoch in range(5):
    model.train()
    for data, label in train_dls:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        target = model(data)
        train_step_loss = loss_fn(target, label) #CrossEntropyLoss
        train_step_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f'Epoch:{epoch+1} | Optim:{optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"]:.4f} | Loss: {train_step_loss:.2f}')
        lrs.append(optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"])
    scheduler.step()
```

**Output**

```
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:1 | Optim:0.0000 | Loss: 0.72
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:2 | Optim:0.0200 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:3 | Optim:0.0400 | Loss: 0.65
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.73
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.71
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.71
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.71
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:4 | Optim:0.0600 | Loss: 0.72
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.70
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.71
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.68
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.71
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.69
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.71
Epoch:5 | Optim:0.0800 | Loss: 0.70
```

In a nutshell, I want to ask how do I find the **correct** learning rate?
Would appreciate if anybody could show how to plot the `learning rate` by `loss` plot.

Comment: To whoever voted to migrate this to Cross Validated: this is a *programming* question, asking how to extract the selected LR after the cyclic LR procedure in Pytorch, not about finding the "best" LR in general (which would be off-topic here indeed). Thus, the question belongs here.

Answer (score 0):

From https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR

you must use `get_last_lr()` to get the last learning rate by this scheduler.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that that's the final learning rate of the scheduler but is that the appropriate learning for my model to train? It just seems to me that it changes based on the number I'm on the epoch. That doesn't seem reliable to me.

Comment: @Snehangu Of course, you are using a learning rate scheduler which changes your learning rate based on certain rules. If you want to keep your learning rate unchanged during the course of training, just pass a constant value when creating an optimizer. Finding a good learning rate (and other hyper-parameters) belongs to the task of hyper-parameter search.